# Calculated date column in using multiple IF-Statements

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Currently, I am creating a calculated column called `Next Meeting Due`

This column is linked to 2 other columns:

> Meeting Frequency -> (which can be monthly, 6 monthly and annually)
>
> Last Meeting Date -> (last meeting)

My current formula is:

```
=IF([Meeting Frequency]="6 Monthly",[Last Meeting Date]+182)
```

This works perfectly fine, however when adding multiple if statements for Monthly/Annually it doesn't work.

In my head the following formula should work:

```
=IF([Meeting Frequency]="6 Monthly"
    ,[Last Meeting Date]+182
   )
   ,[Meeting Frequency]="Monthly"
   ,[Last Meeting Date]+30
```

If anyone has a solution or can point out what I have done wrong please let me know.

This also **doesn't** work:

```
=IF([Meeting Frequency]="6 Monthly"
    ,[Last Meeting Date]+182
   )
   ,IF([Meeting Frequency]="Monthly"
       ,[Last Meeting Date]+30
      )
```

Comment: Always start in Notepad and format your Formula with linebreaks and indents. I did this for your formulas so you can spot yourself where your syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I tested this formular:

```
=IF([Meeting Frequency]="6 Monthly"
        ,DATE(YEAR([Last Meeting Date])
                    ,MONTH([Last Meeting Date])+6
                    ,DAY([Last Meeting Date])
              )
        ,IF([Meeting Frequency]="Monthly"
            ,DATE(YEAR([Last Meeting Date])
                    ,MONTH([Last Meeting Date])+1
                    ,DAY([Last Meeting Date])
                  )
            )
    )
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Thanks to Danny who posted this [link](http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List) to fix the offset.

Comment: Offset can be fixed with the partial formula: ``DATE( YEAR([Last Meeting Date]) , MONTH([Last Meeting Date]) + 6 , DAY([Last Meeting Date]) )`` . See all functions: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 1):

The formula should be like this

```
=IF([Meeting Frequency]="6 Monthly",[Last Meeting Date]+182,IF([Meeting Frequency]="Monthly",[Last Meeting Date]+30))
```

You will need to use nested if in calculated column, your first if statement's closing bracket need to be at end.